# Delphi Android TEdit only number

Tags: android, delphi, numbers, firemonkey

how to make tedit only accept numbers, and reject all buttons except numbers. I can do this on Windows, but on Android I am still confused. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TNumberBox`, from unit `FMX.NumberBox`.

Pay attention to `Min` and `Max` properties though. And also the `ValueType` property, `Integer` as default. Set to `Float` and use `DecimalDigits` property for decimal numbers

Comment: Thanks. But what if I only want an integer positive number, not a decimal? if I change valuetype to integer, it still accepts strings and characters

Comment: oh thank you sir. I just received your update answer. I understand now.

Comment: You are welcome! Your first comment doesn't seem to apply to a `TNumberBox`. I can not enter strings or even characters.